# Is it possible to capture ethernet frames using pure winsock

Tags: c, winsock

I have defined structures for ip packet headers (tcp, udp and icmp) and listening on a raw socket using.

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP)
```

In a loop i cast every packet into the ip header struct and extract tcp, udp or icmp using the predefined structs and the protocol id of the ip packet struct. I know about libcap and wincap, i just want to do it "on my own" :P Is it correct that i cant capture ethernet frames (like arp) using winsock, right? Is there any way to get the frame data without any library except winsock? Maybe creating some kind of AF_PACKET socket?

Someone commented on [Raw Ethernet Frames Using Winsock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766912/raw-ethernet-frames-using-winsock) that "**Nothing below layer 3 is allowed in windows**"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect libpcap installs a network filter driver.  Isn't that the key to making raw packet capture work?

Comment: https://nmap.org/npcap/ installs an NDIS driver. You could write your own, but there are driver signing issues that might slow you down.